# cacheable and searchable support

Tags: spring, ehcache

```
I am using Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE with Ehcache v.2.7.0
```

I wants to perform searchable operation on the cache, i know the manual way to do it as following, is there easy way i can do it using annotation over @Cacheable

```
public List<SourceLite> searchInSourceLite(String searchText){

        Query query = sourceCache.createQuery();

        query.includeKeys();
        query.includeValues();

        Attribute<String> fullNameAttrib = sourceCache.getSearchAttribute("fullName");


        query.addCriteria(fullNameAttrib.ilike("*"+searchText+"*"));

        Results results = query.execute();
        List<Result> records = results.all();
        System.out.println(records.size());

        return new ArrayList<SourceLite>(0);
    }
```

-- Ehcache xml file entry

```
 <cache name="sourceLiteCache" 
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="50000"
            eternal="false" 
            timeToLiveSeconds="10800" 
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">

            <searchable>
                <searchAttribute name="fullName" expression="value.getFullName()" />
                <searchAttribute name="id" expression="value.getId()" />
            </searchable>

        </cache>
```

-- Java Source Class

```
@Cacheable(value=CacheNames.SOURCE_LITE_CACHE)
    @Override
    public List<SourceLite> getAllSourceLite() {
        return sourceDao.getAllSourceLites();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Spring caching abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) does not have a search concept, so no this is not possible.